# Calculate surface area

Tags: webgl, three.js

For a given terrain, how can you calculate its surface area?

As of now, I plan to build the terrain using Three.js with something like:

```
var geo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(300, 300, 10, 10);

for (var i = 0; i < geo.vertices.length; i++)
    geo.vertices[i].y = someHeight; // Makes the flat plain into a terrain
```

Next, if its possible to iterate through each underlying triangle of the geometry (i.e. triangles of TRIANGLE_STRIP given to the WebGL array) the area of each triangle could be summed up to get the total surface area.

Does this approach sound right? If so, how do you determine vertices of individual triangles?

Any other ideas to build the terrain in WebGL/Three.js are welcome.

Comment: What are you going to use the surface area value for?

Comment: @Kevin Hmmm... It's part of the spec which I need to implement and honestly I too don't know what the users of the application would use it for.  Would be great if you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Initially I thought the terrain could be built with the set of known points (point cloud) and then reconstructing its surface; but it turned out to be non-trivial, requiring an algorithm such as Delaunay Triangulation. THREE.PlaneGeometry seemed like another good solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach sounds right and shouldn't be hard to implement.

I'm not familiar with three.js, but I think it's quite easy to determine positions of the vertices. You know that the vertices are evenly distribute between `x=0...300`, `z=0...300` and you know the `y` coordinate. So the `[i,j]`-th vertex has position `[i*300/10, y, j*300/10]`.

You have `10x10` segments in total and each segment consists of 2 triangles. This is where you have to be careful.
The triangles could form two different shapes:

```
------        ------
| \  |        |   /|
|  \ |   or   |  / |
|   \|        | /  |
------        ------
```

which could result in different shape and (I'm not entirely sure about this) into different surface areas.

When you find out how exactly three.js creates the surface, it should be relatively easy to iteratively sum the triangle surfaces.

It would be nice to be able to do the sum without actual iteration over all triangles, but, right now, I don't have any idea how to do it...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've planned on using `THREE.PlaneGeometry` provided by the `three.js` library.  This gives the app a basic mesh to start from.  So I guess triangulating would also be taken care of by three.js.  I think the app need's to know the right data structure (to iterate over triangles) by which triangle data is passed to the WebGL buffer.